# Почему перестал работать выход с сайта Rails (devise)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста как исправить ошибку. При выходе с сайта выкидывает сообщение - Couldn't find Doctor with 'id'=sign_out и указывает на строку

```
@doctor = Doctor.find(params[:id])
```

в контроллере

```
class DoctorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_doctor, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def index
    @doctor = Doctor.all
  end

  def show
    @length =  User.where(doctor_id: params[:id]).size
  end

  private 

  def set_doctor
    @doctor = Doctor.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Раньше с сайта выходил, но теперь такая возможность пропала. Использую гем Devise

UPDATE
routes.rb

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'contact/index'

resources :news
resources :prices
get 'healthy/index'
get 'about/index'

resources :users
resources :doctors

devise_for :doctors, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
root 'users#main'
```

end

Ссылка на выход из сессии

```
<%= link_to 'Вийти', destroy_doctor_session_path %>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите файл роутов и разметку кнопки выхода. Контроллер не при делах.

Comment: @D-side - обновил

Comment: И для полноты картины вывод `rake routes`. В целом я уже вижу, в чём проблема, просто так будет нагляднее.

Comment: @D-side Обновил)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возьмите ваш маршрут **`GET /doctors/sign_out`** и смотрите по списку сверху вниз, по какому правилу он совпадёт первым.

И совпадает он с **`GET /doctors/:id`**, собранным из `resources :doctors`. Почему не **`GET /doctors/sign_out`** (из `devise_for`), если он подходит **лучше**? А *неважно, он первый подходящий*. Он и используется.

Решение простое — поместите вызов `devise_for` **выше** `resources :doctors`, тем самым изменив порядок этих маршрутов в списке так, чтобы первым совпадал **`GET /doctors/sign_out`**.

---

**Альтернативно**, повышенной сложности: не меняя порядок, установите к параметру `:id` в маршруте требование состоять только из цифр, аналогично [примеру из документации](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints):

```
get 'photos/:id', to: 'photos#show', constraints: { id: /[A-Z]\d{5}/ }
```

Это единственный выход, когда маршруты сильно перекрываются. Это не ваш случай, в вашем случае достаточно изменить порядок. Но только первого приёма для разруливания таких проблем в общем случае недостаточно.

Comment: Отлично, большое спасибо за детальное объяснение!